# setAlpha applies to all Drawables with same resource ID, how can I apply to only some?

Tags: android

**Background:**

I've created the following layout:

[image]

I'm trying to apply setAlpha to the Drawable which is used as the ImageButton's background. I only want to apply it to a subset of the buttons so it appears as follows:

[image]

However, it doesn't work correctly. Instead of only some of the buttons, the setAlpha applies to *all* of the buttons, e.g.:

[image]

Because each ImageButton uses the same image, each underlying drawable has the same resource ID. It would be very impractical for me to create a different instance of each image so that they had different resource IDs.

Basically, what I'm doing in code is:

```
    private Drawable GetBlockImage(BlockStatus block)
    {
        Drawable imgBlock = null;

        try
        {
            if (block.inAlarm)
            {
                imgBlock = _resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Block_Alarmed_6);

            }
            else
            {
                var resId = 0;
                switch (block.armState)
                {
                    case BlockStatus.BlockArming.Unset:
                        // *
                        // In the images above, this is the resource ID that is set
                        * //
                        resId = Resource.Drawable.Block_Unset_6;
                        break;
                    case BlockStatus.BlockArming.PartsetA:
                        resId = Resource.Drawable.Block_Armed_6_PartsetA;
                        break;
                    case BlockStatus.BlockArming.PartsetB:
                        resId = Resource.Drawable.Block_Armed_6_PartsetB;
                        break;
                    case BlockStatus.BlockArming.Fullset:
                        resId = Resource.Drawable.Block_Alarmed_6;
                        break;
                }

                imgBlock = _resources.GetDrawable(resId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Handle(_context, ex);
        }

        if (!block.userAllowed)
        {
            imgBlock.SetAlpha(50);
        }

        return imgBlock;
    }
```

**Question:**

How can I apply setAlpha to only a subset of the ImageButtons in my layout? Each ImageButton uses the same resource ID.

Comment: how many drawable objects you are creating?? one object or 6 objects??

Comment: I create the drawable X times. For each of the drawables I need which is determined at runtime I execute `imgBlock = _resources.GetDrawable(resId);` (not because I want to be wasteful, but because there are different decisions to be made depending on circumstances)

Comment: post some of you code of setting drawable to imageview..then we can understand clearly..

Comment: I've updated the question with more specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the alpha to the *drawable*, but to the *ImageButtons*.

You can do that by just doing the following:

```
yourImageButton.setAlpha(50);
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! I don't know why I didn't try that myself. Anyway, 'twerked like Miley. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `d.mutate();` before setting alpha, this leads to, that the drawables DON'T share their state anymore...

```
d.mutate();
d.setAlpha(100);
```